# Rendering template just after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

### The goal

Render a template just after a `click` binding with KnockoutJS.

### The scenario

There is a table on my application and each row of this table is an item. When I click on some item, I will display its details in another container.

I pass all necessary information about this item by parameter and I need to get this parameter as data on a `template` binding — **how can I do this?**

### Illustrative details

Here's my *trigger*:

```
[...]
    <tr data-bind="click: showDetails"></tr>
[...]
```

When someone click on it, displays the following template:

```
<p data-bind="text: itemName"></p>
```

... within the following container:

```
<div class="details" 
     data-bind="template: {name: 'detailsTemplate',
                           data: ~should be the parameter (object)
                                  that "showDetails" sends~}">
</div>
```

The ***final*** DOM should be the following and have to be visible just if I clicked on some item:

```
<div class="details" [...]>
    <p>Microsoft</p>
</div>
```

**Someone knows how can I do this?**

Comment: Does something like this work: http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/KXhxr/

Comment: Turn your comment into an answer, please. Awesome answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a master detail view, a very common practice is to have a "selected" item that the detail view will bind against.

Setting this `selectedItem` from a binding is made easier by the fact that the default parameter sent to functions in a `click` binding is the current binding context, which is the current item in a `foreach` binding. Couple this with the fact that observable are functions, you can set the `selectedItem` directly like this:

`data-bind="click: $parent.selectedItem"`

Then all you have to do is bind some detail view against the `selectedItem`. Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/KXhxr) for a simple example.

Comment: Thank you Tyrsius for your amazing answer — works perfectly. By the way, I have one more question: do you know how can I pass to `selectedItem` some `computed value`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean